# 'unable to load asset' how can i fix this error?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, directory

Many people ask me to check pubspec.yaml. But I don't know what's wrong.
Can you copy the answers for me?
(in vscode)

I did it like this.

```
flutter:

[2 whitespaces or 1 tab]assets:
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- assets/images/
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- assets/icons/
```

My pubspec.yaml :
flutter:
uses-material-design: true

```
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
```

My Folder

Comment: How are you referring the image in the code ?

Comment: post full pubspec.yaml and how you reference assets in code